# Modify javascript code to iterate through all variables in the form

Tags: javascript, post, variables

I have the following code that worked fine till now as I decided to add more variables to the form.  How can I make this function smart and itterate and pass all the variables in the form?

```
    function getquerystring(strFormName) {
    var form     = document.forms[strFormName];
    var word = form.clock_code.value;
    qstr = 'clock_code=' + escape(word);  // NOTE: no '?' before querystring
    return qstr;
}
```

complete JS code @ [pastie](http://pastie.org/691190)

Comment: You should not use escape.  It's deprecated because it does not correctly URI escape the '+' character.  See http://www.duzengqiang.com/blog/post/494.html

Comment: It also gets non-ASCII characters wrong. Don't use `escape`, it is almost always the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *looks* like you're serializing a form to a querystring? If that's the case, then this is one place where a JavaScript library is really nice.

Each of these will serialize the first form on the page to a querystring.

```
// ExtJS
var str = Ext.lib.Ajax.serializeForm(Ext.select('form').elements[0]);

// jQuery
var str = $("form").serialize(); 

// MooTools
var str = $$('form').toQueryString();

// PrototypeJS
var str = $$('form')[0].serialize();
```

You can see some other methods and how they compare at http://jquery.malsup.com/form/comp/

Comment: I am using jquery, so I'll figure out if I can do that.

Comment: You should be. $('form[name="foo"]') would get a form named 'foo'. If you want to pass in a form name to a function you could do `function serializeForm(formName) { return $('form[name='+formName+']').serialize(); }`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function formToQueryString(form) {
  var elements = form.elements;
  var cgi = [];
  for (var i = 0, n = elements.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var el = elements[i];
    if (!el.name) { continue; }
    if (el.tagName === 'INPUT' && (el.type === 'checkbox' || el.type === 'radio')
        && !el.checked) {
      continue;
    }
    cgi.push(encodeURIComponent(el.name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(el.value));
  }
  return cgi.length ? '?' + cgi.join('&') : '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are all simple fields, the following should work just fine (didn't test it, though - sorry if it doesn't "compile"):

```
function getquerystring(strFormName) {
    var qstr = '';
    var form     = document.forms[strFormName];
    var elements = form.elements;
    var first = true;
    for (elem in elements) {
       var word = elem.value;
       var name = elem.name;
       if (first) {
         first = false;
       } else {
         qstr = qstr + '&';
       } 
       qstr = qstr + name + '=' + escape(word);  
    }
    return qstr;
}
```

**Adding info on supporting multiple Element types:**

The question only mentioned text fields so I assumed the easier answer would suffice.  Wrong!

Glad you're able to use JQuery (which rocks), but for completeness I'll just flesh this out with a bit of info on how to build your own "dynamic form handler".

First, you have to add checking on the class of elem, like so:

```
   function isCheckbox(o){ return (o && o.constructor == Checkbox) }
```

and you have to then do something a little different depending on the type of object you are looking at.

For example:

```
   for (var elem in elements) {
     var value = '';
     var name = elem.name; 
     if (isCheckbox(elem)) {
        value = elem.checked ? 'true' : 'false';
     } else if (isSingleSelect(elem)) {
        var index = elem.selectedIndex;
        if(selected_index > 0) { 
          value = elem.options[selected_index].value;
        }
     }
   }
```

There may be situations where you have to turn values into something that is meaningful to your app, like in a multiple-select combo box.  You could send one name=value pair for each value or roll them into a comma-seperated list or the like - it all depends on your app.  But with this *approach* one can certainly build the "dynamic form handler" that fits their specific needs.

Check out this article for helpful stuff about how to process each form field type:   http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-get-form.htm

Comment: I'm trying this out, will post back shorty.

Comment: You forgot to var declare elem, you shouldn't use escape fir reasons I commented on above, and the for in loop doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Be warned that if `for (elem in elements)` comes across a radio set, checkgroup, fieldset, or the like, then "elem" will not have the .value or .name properties available... "elem" may very well be an array of other elements or a "non-element"...

Comment: Also agree on the "for in" not working as is suggested. Sorry, my comment didn't reflect that, but the point remains.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you're only grabbing the `clock_code` element value, and ignoring the rest. Here's a replacement I wrote up:

```
function getquerystring(strFormName) {
    var qstr = '', word = '';
    var key = 0;
    var form     = document.forms[strFormName];
    var fields = ['clock_code', 'message', 'type'];

    for (var i = 0; i<fields.length; i++) {
        key  = fields[i];
        word = form[key].value;
        if (qstr && qstr.length > 0) {
            qstr += '&';
        }
        qstr += encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(word);
    }

    return qstr;
}
```

Benjamin's approach is a bit more flexible; mine only queries those fields specifically named in the `fields` array

Comment: Thank you, I need to be flexible as differant forms will call on this function.  Thank you